# What should I do with "here are some of my answers that may help"?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, link-only-answers, specific-answer

There is a question that reads like

> I do not understand exactly what an application server like Tomcat,
> Weblogic, Websphere, GlassFish etc. does.
> ... I do not understand what exactly an application server does and **how** it does it; if you know some good tutorial (or book) about this, or are willing to give a more detailed explanation about this, please answer.

The accepted answer is shown below

[image]

I believe this is just a collection of links.

I've read some questions about link-only answers from both MSO and MSE and the consensus is *"We don't need link-only answers, flag them as NAA or VLQ"*. This particular answer does look like an answer to me, albeit not a good one. I couldn't flag it as VLQ because of its score.

I also discovered [a closely related meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209145/260312):

> **Q:** The accepted answer with 32 upvotes is just a link. [...] Is this flagable? I know in the good ol' days SO was a bit
> more lawless, but how should it be dealt with now?
>
> **A:** I went ahead and
> converted that answer to a comment, as we would do today if flagged.
> In particular since there is another, much more detailed and also highly voted answer.

Although I doubt that this answer can be converted to a comment easily.

To be fair, it does have a tiny bit of explanation somewhere between those links:

> The container gives the application a proxy and intercepts calls and
> performs tasks before invoking the actual bean.

Was this sentence the reason my custom flag was declined ( *flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer* )?

If I were wrong to flag that answer, how should I have dealt with it?

Comment: Did you vote to close the question, too, or is it already closed? Because that's a recommendation question, and is the source of the problem. The answer is just a symptom. (I recall reading that mods will decline flags on occasion because of this, but I could be remembering wrong.)

Comment: @Kendra I did, the question is now closed. However I think that other answers are much more useful, and this answer is kind of a distraction.

Comment: *"Was this sentence the reason my custom flag was declined"* what was your custom flag?

Comment: *"Technically it's a link-only "here are some of the StackOverflow answers I've written that give some insight as to how application servers work" kind of answer."* Yeah, I should have said something more constructive. @codeMagic

Comment: Seems link only to me because the text that is there describes what the links talk about so that's kind of close. That's probably why. There's also the whole "Don't punish the answerers for bad questions" thing

Comment: @codeMagic what's that thing? If someone answers an obvious candidate for closure, I thought we were allowed to rip their toenails out for making the site messy?

Comment: The site is already messy because it is littered with ripped out toenails!

Comment: @BillWoodger in a lot of cases, I think we should!

Comment: @BillWoodger It's about not regarding something as a bad answer by association with a bad question. Even an answer that does answer a bad question is answering the question, so the focus should be on dealing with the bad question.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan but if the question *can* be answered, why would it be an obvious closure candidate?

Comment: @BillWoodger Off topic questions can still be answered. Too broad questions can be attempted. Typos can be answered. An unclear question can be attempted if not correctly answered despite lacking information.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Really? So they get an upvote, and even when closed, the crap still hangs around? You're kidding, right?

Comment: @BillWoodger If the question is fixed then they deserve the upvote unless the answer becomes irrelevant. If not, I believe the system deletes the question and reputation on those answers gets removed anyway.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan you'd best check out how the auto-deleting of closed questions works. It isn't like that. OK, I'd best check it as well, just in case it is...